# CSS: align form options

Tags: html, css

I need to replicate this form:

[image]

As you can see in the image, the options in "Select a quantity" part are perfectly aligned.

Not so my much my html:

[image]

**How can I make it perfectly aligned as in the first image?**

I'm using bootstrap 4.

Note: I'm rendering this html from a Django FORM, and as you'll see some values have extra blank spaces.I'm trying to figure out how not to render those values with blank spaces around (how to trim them).

**HTML:**

```
<form action="/post_url_tamanioscantidades/" method="post">
  <input type="hidden" name="csrfmiddlewaretoken" value="Phabzw1RqbPnGf2wKo4zoHqWLXogOcfbFR38uxXLeoHeBigRBXhXqO0q9mhFimsB">

<div id="tamanios">
   <legend> Selecciona un tamaño</legend>
      <ul>
        <li>
           <span>
              <input type="radio" name="tamanios" value="2x2" id="id_tamanios_0" required>
                                                    2&quot; x 2&quot; </span>
        </li>
        <li>
          <span>
            <input type="radio" name="tamanios" value="3x3" id="id_tamanios_1" required>
                                                    3&quot; x 3&quot;
         </span>
        </li>
         <li>
           <span>
             <input type="radio" name="tamanios" value="4x4" id="id_tamanios_2" required>
                                                    4&quot; x 4&quot;
           </span>
         </li>
         <li>
           <span>
             <input type="radio" name="tamanios" value="5x5" id="id_tamanios_3" required>
                                                    5&quot; x 5&quot;
           </span>
       </li>
   </ul>

 </div>


 <div id="cantidades">

    <legend> Selecciona la cantidad</legend>

         <ul>
             <li>
              <span>
                <input type="radio" name="cantidades" value="100" id="id_cantidades_0" required>
                                                50
               </span>                                                   <span>$69</span>
               <span class="savings">Ahorra 39%</span>
          </li>
          <li>
             <span>
                <input type="radio" name="cantidades" value="100" id="id_cantidades_1" required>
                                                100 </span>
                                                <span>$120</span>
<span class="savings">Ahorra 77%</span>
          </li>
          <li>
          <span>
            <input type="radio" name="cantidades" value="150" id="id_cantidades_2" required>
                                                    150
            </span>
                                                    <span>$509</span>
           <span class="savings">Ahorra 60%</span
         </li>
       </ul>

    </div>

  <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
</form>
```

Comment: You could use a table?

Comment: Sure, I'm a backend developer. Please, show me how.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using Table

```css
table tr td {
  padding-left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<form action="/post_url_tamanioscantidades/" method="post">
  <input type="hidden" name="csrfmiddlewaretoken" value="Phabzw1RqbPnGf2wKo4zoHqWLXogOcfbFR38uxXLeoHeBigRBXhXqO0q9mhFimsB">

  <div id="tamanios">
    <legend> Selecciona un tamaño</legend>
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <input type="radio" name="tamanios" value="2x2" id="id_tamanios_0" required> 2&quot; x 2&quot; </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <input type="radio" name="tamanios" value="3x3" id="id_tamanios_1" required> 3&quot; x 3&quot;
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <input type="radio" name="tamanios" value="4x4" id="id_tamanios_2" required> 4&quot; x 4&quot;
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <input type="radio" name="tamanios" value="5x5" id="id_tamanios_3" required> 5&quot; x 5&quot;
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>

  </div>


  <div id="cantidades">

    <legend> Selecciona la cantidad</legend>

    <table>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <input type="radio" name="cantidades" value="100" id="id_cantidades_0" required> 50
        </td>
        <td>$69</td>
        <td class="savings">Ahorra 39%</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <input type="radio" name="cantidades" value="100" id="id_cantidades_1" required> 100 </td>
        <td>$120</td>
        <td class="savings">Ahorra 77%</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <input type="radio" name="cantidades" value="150" id="id_cantidades_2" required> 150
        </td>
        <td>$509</td>
        <td class="savings">Ahorra 60%</td>
      </tr>
    </table>

  </div>

  <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

Comment: Do not use tables in non-tabular data.

Answer (score 2):

Try this: http://jsfiddle.net/x1hphsvb/10502/

```
ul li {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  width: 200px;
  text-align: left;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try:

```
ul li {
  text-align: left;
}
```